# Are Wolf spaces flag manifolds?

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, flag-varieties, holonomy, quaternionic-geometry

It's all in the title: **Are [Wolf spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion-K%C3%A4hler_symmetric_space) [flag manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_flag_variety)**? Both are group quotients of semi-simple Lie groups. In the Grassmannian case this is so, and I always tacitly assumed it extended to the general case. However, I recently read this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52396/are-there-topological-restrictions-to-the-existence-of-almost-quaternionic-struc) by Moroianu, where he says that

> the quaternionic projective spaces $ℍP_n$ are quaternion-Kähler, but have no almost complex structure

I now think my assumption is probably false. Can someone please help "de-confuse" me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flag manifolds have the form $G/C(S)$ where $C(S)$ is the centralizer (in $G$) of its center $S$ (a torus).

Most $G/H$ in the [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion-K%C3%A4hler_symmetric_space) don't have this form, for $H$ has discrete center in each case except the complex Grassmannians $\mathrm{SU}(p+2)/\mathrm S(\mathrm{U}(p)\times\mathrm{U}(2))$ and $\mathrm{SO}(6)/\mathrm{SO}(2)\mathrm{SO}(4)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let me just remark that there is a 1-1 correspondence between compact connected homogeneous complex contact manifolds and compact simply connected quaternionic symmetric spaces. It is actually described in the original [paper](https://math.berkeley.edu/~jawolf/publications.pdf/paper_024.pdf) by Wolf, theorem 6.1. The correspondence is given by bundles with fibers being 2-spheres:

$$
G/L\cdot S^1 \to G/L\cdot Sp(1)
$$